# About the 'minimum triangle' which includes a convex bounded closed set

Tags: euclidean-geometry, triangles

**Question** : Is the following true?

"Letting $K$ be a convex bounded closed set on a plane, then there exists a triangle $M$, which includes $K$, such that $|M|\le 2|K|$. Here, $|M|,|K|$ is the area of $M,K$ respectively."

**Motivation** : First, I've thought about the case that $K$ is a parallelogram. Then, I reached the above expectation, but I can neither prove this nor find any counterexample. Can anyone help?

*Update* : I crossposted to [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/146179/about-the-minimum-triangle-which-includes-a-convex-bounded-closed-set).

Comment: @ChristianBlatter: Well, I meant that $|M|\le 2|K|$ for any $K$. Then, I expect $2$ would be the optimal constant because of the fact that if $K$ is a parallelogram and $M$ is a triangle which includes $K$, then $|M|\le 2|K|$ always holds.

Comment: You are right: For a parallelogram we need the factor $2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm posting an answer just to inform that the question has received an answer by Joseph O'Rourke on MO.

He introduced [this page](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TriangleCircumscribing.html).